# PusherJS and Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, pusher, pusher-js

I want to watch pusher events and update the local state or rerender component.

My current way to follow pusher notification.

```
...
methods: {
    refreshSlider() {
      const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_ID, {
        cluster: "eu",
      });
      Pusher.logToConsole = true;
      const channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");
      channel.bind("my-event", async function () {
        // alert("1");
        console.log(this.sliders); //undefined!
      });
    },
  },
...
async mounted() {
    .....
    this.refreshSlider();
  },
```

Please help me, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing your `this` scope in the `my-event` handler. You should be using a fat arrow function instead of a normal function:

```
...
methods: {
    refreshSlider() {
      const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_ID, {
        cluster: "eu",
      });
      Pusher.logToConsole = true;
      const channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");
      channel.bind("my-event", async () => {
        // alert("1");
        console.log(this.sliders); //should exist now
      });
    },
  },
...
async mounted() {
    .....
    this.refreshSlider();
  },
```

Here's a great article that goes more into depth about `this` scope and fat arrow functions: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881/